# python-Can't import module in Pycharm while I can import the same module in terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed [essentia](https://github.com/MTG/essentia) by 

`brew install essentia --HEAD`

message:

`Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/yangyy/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/yangyy/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth`

I did as the message instructed and installed `essentia` successfully.
The module can be imported in terminal:

`Python 2.7.11 (default, Feb 23 2016, 00:59:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
-import essentia
-exit()`


`$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python`

I use Pycharm as my IDE. I tried all the interpreter, but still can't import this module.

In python, I tried:

```
>>> import essentia
>>> reload(essentia)
<module 'essentia' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/essentia/__init__.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm wont take package dependencies instead it contains package you should initiate for your projects.. 
so, for that, You should go to

```
settings -> project Interpreter
```

then choose your project and check your packages are there then click,

```
apply <-button
```

that's it

Comment: I've tried this. The problem is I can't find the module installed there.

Comment: are you  using virtualenv? if not means try to create and install dependencies under virtualenv then try this. because i got from that only...

Comment: I tried to use virtualenv, but I'm not quite understand how it works. Eventually I installed the module under global environment. I've edited the question. Now I know the path of the module and I'm trying to add path manually.

Comment: create virtual env , activate your virtualenv by source bin/activate,  install package under your virtual env - dont use sudo it will install globally instead within env , then open your virtualenv directory from pycharm instead of your project directory. then choose settings project interpreter definitely you will find your packages :)